# How to fix a task test in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a table called Jurisdiction and created that task to update the kind column:

```
namespace :populate_jurisdiction do
  desc "Populate column kind of jurisdiction model"
  task kind: :environment do
    Jurisdiction.all.each { |jurisdiction|
      case (jurisdiction.kind.nil? || jurisdiction.kind.blank?)
        when jurisdiction.name.parameterize == "federal"
        jurisdiction.kind = 1
        when jurisdiction.name.parameterize == "estadual"
        jurisdiction.kind = 2
        when jurisdiction.name.parameterize == "municipal"
          jurisdiction.kind = 3
        when jurisdiction.name.parameterize == "privado"
        jurisdiction.kind = 4
      end
      jurisdiction.save!
    }
  end
end
```

Then I created that test

```
require "spec_helper"

Rails.application.load_tasks

describe "populate_jurisdiction:kind" do
  context "when update kind column of jurisdiction" do
    let(:federal) { create(:jurisdiction, name: "Federal", kind: nil) }
    let(:state) { create(:jurisdiction, name: "Estadual", kind: nil) }
    let(:municipal) { create(:jurisdiction, name: "Municipal", kind: '') }
    let(:particular) { create(:jurisdiction, name: "Privado", kind: '') }

    it "when kind column is updated" do
      Rake::Task["populate_jurisdiction:kind"].invoke
      expect(federal.kind).to eq(1)
      expect(state.kind).to eq(2)
      expect(municipal.kind).to eq(3)
      expect(particular.kind).to eq(4)
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the task in rails console it works, but when I run the test, I got this error

```
Failures:

  1) populate_jurisdiction:kind when update kind column of jurisdiction when kind column is updated
     Failure/Error: expect(federal.kind).to eq(1)
     
       expected: 1
            got: nil
     
       (compared using ==)
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I fix this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking the rake task *before* any of the Jurisdiction's are created. When you say this:

```
let(:federal) { create(:jurisdiction, name: "Federal", kind: nil) }
```

that will create `federal` when you first access it in a test and then remember that for the duration of the test. So there is no `federal` until after your rake task runs. If you used `let!` instead of `let` and reloaded the jurisdictions after the task runs, you'd get better results.

---

BTW, your rake task doesn't work they way you think it does. There are two forms of `case`:

```
case expr
when value1
  ...
when value2
  ...
end
```

and

```
case
when expr1
  ...
when expr2
  ...
end
```

You're using the first form when you mean to be using the second and your code is working by accident. I suspect that all your `kind`s are `nil` when you run this, otherwise you'd end up doing:

```
case false
...
end
```

and you'd go into the first branch where the `jurisdiction.name.parameterize` test failed.

Your task should look more like:

```
Jurisdiction.all.reject { |j| j.kind.blank? }.each do |jurisdiction|
  case jurisdiction.name.parameterize
  when 'federal'
    jurisdiction.kind = 1
  when 'estadual'
    jurisdiction.kind = 2
  when 'municipal'
    jurisdiction.kind = 3
  when 'privado'
    jurisdiction.kind = 4
  end
  jurisdiction.save!
end
```

or:

```
Jurisdiction.all.reject { |j| j.kind.blank? }.each do |jurisdiction|
  jurisdiction.kind = case jurisdiction.name.parameterize
                      when 'federal' then 1
                      when 'estadual' then 2
                      when 'municipal' then 3
                      when 'privado' then 4
                      end
  jurisdiction.save!
end
```

If `kind` is an integer then `kind.blank?` will only true when `kind.nil?` so that can be pushed into the database:

```
Jurisdiction.where(kind: nil).each do |jurisdiction|
  jurisdiction.kind = case jurisdiction.name.parameterize
                      when 'federal' then 1
                      when 'estadual' then 2
                      when 'municipal' then 3
                      when 'privado' then 4
                      end
  jurisdiction.save!
end
```

and it looks like `#parameterize` in this case is only going to be converting the `name` to lower case so push all the logic into the database:

```
# This is an SQL CASE expression, not a Ruby one
Jurisdiction.where(kind: nil).update_all(%q(
  kind = case lower(name)
         when 'federal' then 1
         when 'estadual' then 2
         when 'municipal' then 3
         when 'privado' then 4
         end
))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke the rake task, there are no jurisdictions, that's why you're getting `nil`. For example, *federal* jurisdiction is only created after the rake task when you call `federal.kind`.

```
require "spec_helper"

Rails.application.load_tasks

describe "populate_jurisdiction:kind" do
  context "when update kind column of jurisdiction" do
    let(:federal) { create(:jurisdiction, name: "Federal", kind: nil) }
    let(:state) { create(:jurisdiction, name: "Estadual", kind: nil) }
    let(:municipal) { create(:jurisdiction, name: "Municipal", kind: '') }
    let(:particular) { create(:jurisdiction, name: "Privado", kind: '') }

    it "when kind column is updated" do
      # NOTE: jurisdictions are not created until `let` blocks are called.
      federal
      state
      municipal
      particular      

      Rake::Task["populate_jurisdiction:kind"].invoke

      # NOTE: `let` return values are memoized, second call will just
      #        retrieve the value. You have to reload the models as well
      #        to get the updated values from the database.
      expect(federal.reload.kind).to eq(1)
      expect(state.reload.kind).to eq(2)
      expect(municipal.reload.kind).to eq(3)
      expect(particular.reload.kind).to eq(4)
    end
  end
end
```

*https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-11/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let*

Comment: Alternatively, use `let!` instead of `let`.